# angularjs directive error:[nonassign]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to use angular1.x directive,and get this error:

> angular.js:14700 Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' in attribute 'showPageCount' used with directive 'ngPage' is non-assignable!

It seems like i do not sign the property in directive.
How can i make it works?

[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ns4P.png)

[ngPageTemplate.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrJUD.png)

ng-page.js:

```
angular.module('ngPage', [])
    .directive('ngPage', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          pageNo: '=',
          pageSize: '=',
          totalCount: '=',
          pageChange: "&",
          showPageCount: '='
        },
        templateUrl: './ngPageTemplate.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.showPageCount = scope.showPageCount ? scope.showPageCount : 5;
          scope.pageCount = Math.ceil(scope.totalCount / scope.pageSize);
          scope.hasPre = scope.pageNo > 1;
          scope.preNo = scope.hasPre ? scope.pageNo - 1 : scope.pageNo;
          scope.hasNext = scope.pageNo < scope.pageCount;
          scope.nextNo = scope.hasNext ? scope.pageNo + 1 : scope.pageNo;

          scope.goPage = function (pageNo) {
            if (scope.pageNo !== pageNo) {
              scope.pageNo = pageNo;
              scope.pageChange();
            }
          };
          scope.getPageList = function () {
            var list = [];
            if (scope.pageCount <= scope.showPageCount) {
              for (var i = 1; i < scope.pageCount + 1; i++) {
                list.push(i);
              }
            } else {
              var startNo = scope.pageNo - scope.showPageCount / 2;
              var endNo = scope.pageNo + scope.showPageCount / 2;
              if (startNo < 1) {
                //前几页
                startNo = 1;
                for (var i = 0; i < scope.showPageCount; i++) {
                  list.push(startNo++);
                }
              } else if (endNo > scope.pageCount) {
                //后几页
                endNo = angular.copy(scope.pageCount);
                for (var i = scope.showPageCount; i >= 0; i--) {
                  list.unshift(endNo--);
                }
              } else {
                //中间页
                startNo = Math.ceil(startNo);
                for (var i = 0; i < scope.showPageCount; i++) {
                  list.push(startNo++);
                }
              }
            }
            return list;
          };
          scope.pageList = scope.getPageList();
        }
      };

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont be able to use the `showPageCount` parameter inside the directive scope inside the directive `link` function. If you want to use that in link function you must pass the value in `ng-model-options` as

```
<input type="text" ng-model="yourModel" 
ng-model-options='{ debounce: 600, showpagecount: scopecountvalue }' 
ng-page/>
```

and use inside directive link function as.

```
.directive('ngPage', function () {    
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            function inputValue(val) {  
                var pageCount = ctrl.$options.showpagecount;
            }
            ctrl.$parsers.push(inputValue);
        }
    };
})
```

Now the value will be accessible inside link function.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: So can I declare a property inside the directive,and  it's stand alone with the outside?Like the property without @Input() and @Output() in angular2 component

Comment: I want to let showPageCount can be passes into directive and also can not.Can it be realized?

Comment: Thank you very much,your answer gives me a lot of inspiration,and let me deepen my understanding of scope and directive.I modify my code and it works.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Nitheesh.

this is new code:

html:

```
<ng-page page-no="pageNo" page-size="pageSize" page-change="pageChange($event)" total-count="totalCount" show-page-count="6"></ng-page>
```

scope inside directive:

```
        scope: {
          pageNo: '=',
          pageSize: '=',
          totalCount: '=',
          pageChange: "&",
          showPageCount: '@'
        }
```

goPage function inside link:

scope.pageChange({$event: {pageNo: pageNo}});